# Jquery UI Button on OpenLayers popup - select only fires once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, openlayers

I have a html openlayers popup that I generate in my web app , that contains a JQuery button with a menu. The menu displays fine, but the `select` event for the menu only triggers the first time, from then on it doesn't respond. Any ideas why?

Here is the Javascript

```
$("#popup_actions")
    .button({
        text: false,
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-gear",
            secondary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
        }
    })
    .click(function () {
        console.log(this);
        var menu = $(this).parent().next().show().position({
            my: "left top",
            at: "left bottom",
            of: this
        });
        // "chicken" (ahem) is the name of the containing div, for some reason using $(document) didn't work
        $("#chicken").one("click", function () {
            menu.hide();
        });
        return false;
    })
    .parent()
        .buttonset()
        .next()
            .hide()
            .menu({select: function(e) {
                console.log("The menu was selected", event);
            }});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div style="width:60px;float:left">
    <div>
        <button id="popup_actions">Actions</button>
    </div>
    <ul style="width:200px">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-star"></span>Find in rack</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-star"></span>Find in tree</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-star"></span>Change Activity Report</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-star"></span>Link State Change History Report</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Edit:

I managed to get this into a jsfiddle that shows the behaviour not working. It's definitely an issue with OpenLayers. http://jsfiddle.net/mattwoberts/JRmKN/13/ - add a polygon to the map, and then go into popup mode and open the popup to see the menu - the select event will only fire once.

Comment: Do you see the problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/J5rVP/13/)?

Comment: Worryingly, no! Hmm, so it must be related to the way I render that content then. I'll try to make a jsfiddle that recreates it

Comment: Added edits with recreatable jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood the problem, but if it is just the select, there's a typo error, you should change the line

```
console.log("The menu was selected", event);
```

to

```
console.log("The menu was selected", e);
```

Because the variable is named e not event.

Comment: Fair catch, and that was indeed a typo, but it's not related to the issue I'm having.